# why IFormFile blob is null despite setting 200MB for MultipartBodyLengthLimit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

For my .Net 7 web api app, I sets `MultipartBodyLengthLimit` to 200 MB.

```
builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 200217728;
        });
```

Now I am trying to upload even less size 160MB file to the endpoint, I am always getting `null` for `IFormFile file`. What's the reason here?

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("Upload")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
    {
        var result = await _fileService.UploadAsync(file);
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Comment: Did you check `Request.Form.Files[0]` is null also? Or having a model that has a `ICollection<IFormFile>` property on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add ASP.NET Core Request length limit for application running on Kestrel:

```
builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue; // if don't set default value is: 30 MB
});
```

Then Form's MultipartBodyLengthLimit:

```
builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 6104857600;
});
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. I also figured out same :)